# Wrong Securimage verification code still sends the form

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

First time poster, be gentle.

I have a form with a .php processing script that worked fine for the longest time except for the fact that I started to receive spam. I did some research on Captcha's and came across Securimage which was (supposedly) one of the easiest to implement. I downloaded the files and installed it into my script. I came across two problems.

1. The form was still sending if the captcha was left blank (it still notified me that it was blank).
2. The form was still sending if the captcha was wrong (it still notified me that it was wrong).

You can see it in action here: `http://216.119.71.44/contact/`

I "patched" issue 1 just by making the field a required field. I need some help fixing number 2. Below is my code and you can find the documentation for securimage [here](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/):

contact.php:

```
<?php 
$thisPage = "Contact";
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
$date = date('F j, Y');

// check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    // sends the message to recipient
    ini_set("SMTP","mail.abcprintingink.com");

    // Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
    ini_set("smtp_port","587");

    // Please specify the return address to use 

    $to = 'paulr@abcprintingink.com'; //recipient's email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $subject = 'Online Form Submission';
    $expected = array('fname','lname','email','phone','comments','captcha_code');
    $required = array('fname','lname','email','phone','comments','captcha_code','');
    $headers = "From: Technical Staffing Solutions";

    // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    $receiptHeader = "From: Technical Staffing Solutions";
    $receiptSubject = "Copy of your form submission";
    $receipt = "Hello " . $fname . "," . "\n" . "Below is a copy of the message you sent to us on " . $date . ". We will contact you as soon as possible. Thank you!" . "\n\n" . $_POST['comments'];
    mail($from,$receiptSubject,$receipt,$receiptHeader); 

    // detailed processing script (checks for errors)
    require('../include/processmail.php');
}
?>

<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<?php 
// Various on submit mail messages
    if ($mailSent)  { 
        echo "<div id=\"form-success\"><div>&#x2713;</div><p>Thank you " . $fname . ", your message has been sent.</p></div>"; 
    } 
    elseif (($_POST && $suspect) || ($_POST && isset($errors['mailfail']))) { 
        echo "<div id=\"form-error\"><div>!</div><p>Your message could not be sent. Please try again.</p></div>"; 
    }
    elseif ($missing || $errors) { 
        echo "<div id=\"form-error\"><div>!</div><p>Please fill out the required fields and try again.</p></div>"; 
    }
?>  
<form id="getquote" method="post" action="" style="float:left;">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" 
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('fname', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>> 

    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" 
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('lname', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>> 

    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" 
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('email', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>> 

    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" 
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('phone', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($phone, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>>  

    <textarea placeholder="How can I help you?" id="comments" name="comments" 
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('comments', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>> </textarea><br>

    <!-- Captcha -->
    <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
    <a href="#" style="font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; color: #333; text-decoration: none;" title="Reload a new image" onClick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">&#x21bb;</a>
    <input type="text" id="captcha_code" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6"
    <?php if ($missing && in_array('captcha_code', $missing)) { ?>style="border: 1px solid #cc0000;" 
    <?php } if ($missing || $errors) { echo 'value="' . htmlentities($captcha_code, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"'; } ?>>   

    <!-- Submit -->
    <div style="width:292px;"><input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="SUBMIT"></div>
</form>
```

processmail.php:

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

$suspect = false;                                           //assume nothing is suspect
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';                     //create a pattern to locate suspect phrases

function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {             //function to check for suspect phrases
    if (is_array($val)) {                                   //if the variable is an array, loop thorugh each element and pass it recursively back to the same function
        foreach ($val as $item) {
            isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
        }
    } else {
        if(preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
            $suspect = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!$suspect) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);   //assign to temporary variable and strip whitespace if not an array
        if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {    //if empty and requires, add to $missing array
            $missing[] = $key;
        } elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
            ${$key} = $temp;                                //otherwise, assign to a variable of the same name as $key
        }
    }
}

if (!$suspect && !empty($email)) {
    $validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($validemail) {
        $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $validemail";
    } else {
        $errors['email'] = true;
    }
}

$mailSent = false;
if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {                   //go ahead only if not suspect and all required fields are ok
    $message = "";
    foreach($expected as $item) {                           //loop through the $expected array
        if (isset(${$item}) && !empty(${$item})) {
            $val = ${$item};
        } else {
            $val = 'Not Selected';                          //if it has no value, assign 'not selected'
        }
        if (is_array($val)) {                               //if an array, expand as comma-separated string
            $val = implode(', ', $val);
        }
        $item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);   //replace underscores and hyphens in the label with spaces
        $message .= ucfirst($item).": $val\r\n\r\n";        //add label and value to the message body
    }
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);                      //limit the line length to 70 characters

    $mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if (!$mailSent) {
        $errors['mailfail'] = true;
    }
}


include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Securimage needs to be a field implemented in a form and in your first php file not only do you not have a form, but you are calling the `mail()` function before the captcha form is even displayed. I also don't see any calls to the functions in processmail.php.

Comment: I added my form code to the original post. Sorry about that.

In processmail.php I moved the securimage stuff from the bottom to before `if (!$suspect) {` and it seemed to stop the problem. But I wonder if this not sufficient enough... I'm still learning so hopefully someone could explain why what I did is correct or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you are still sending the email out before the form is presented. That functionality should be added to the section of the securimage code where it tells you to process the form is the captcha was successfully filled in.